# Riemann Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Q. Compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1}+\frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+\cdots+\frac{2^{n/n}}{n+1/n}\right)$$
using integral.

One obvious method is to squeeze it using $$2^{(a-1)/n}<\frac{2^{a/n}}{n+a/n}<2^{a/n}$$
and using intermediate value theorem such that $$\exists c\in({(a-1)/n},a/n) : 2^c=\frac{2^{a/n}}{n+a/n}$$
hence the result. $$\int_0^1 2^x \, dx$$.

Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, it is simply a Riemann integral, but because, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the $n$ in the denominator dominates the $k/n \, \forall k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, that piece in the denominator may simply be ignored, and the sum in the limit is

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n} = \int_0^1 dx \: 2^x$$

Comment: OK! cool. and why do we ignore the same quantity in denominator but not in numerator? Merely because we know it should somehow be in the form that is easily reimann integrable?

Comment: No, because it is simply negligible in the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$ next to $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let denote
$$S_n=\left(\frac{2^{1/n}}{n+1}+\frac{2^{2/n}}{n+1/2}+...+\frac{2^{n/n}}{n+1/n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1/k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{1+1/nk}.$$
It's obvious that $S_n $ is not a Riemann Sum but we'll show that we can approximate it by the Riemann sum
$$T_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k/n},$$
and $\{T_n\}$ converges to $\int_0^1 2^x dx$.
Let's now prove that the sequence $\{T_n-S_n\}_n$ converges to $0$ to acheive the proof.

We  have 
$$0\leq T_n-S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k/n}\frac{1/nk}{1+1/nk}\leq\frac{1}{n}n2^{n/n}\frac{1/n}{1+1/n^2}\leq\frac{2}{n}$$
and by squeeze theorem we conclude.